# Using Synchronized Keyword in threads, but result is not correct?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to make use of the keyword "synchronized" but the results are not correct. I'm not able to figure out why call to third object is given before the second one.

Expected Output:

```
hello
synchronized
world
```

Output - What i'm getting

```
hello
world
synchronized
```

Below is the code I am using:

```
class Callme{
 synchronized void call(String msg){
  System.out.print("["+msg);

 try{
Thread.sleep(1000);
 }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
   System.out.println("]");
     }  
      }


class Caller implements Runnable{
   String msg;
   Callme target;
   Thread t;
   public Caller(Callme targ, String s){
      target=targ;
      msg=s;
      t=new Thread(this);
      t.start();
    }

  public void run(){
  target.call(msg);
   } 

}
 class Synch{
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Callme target=new Callme();
    Caller c1=new Caller(target,"hello");
    Caller c2=new Caller(target,"Synchronized");
    Caller c3=new Caller(target,"world");

try{
   System.out.println("Waiting for the threads to end");
   c1.t.join();
   c2.t.join();
   c3.t.join();
   }catch(InterruptedException ie){} 

   }    
 }
```

Comment: That's not the output of your code. You would have `[` in the output, for one thing...

Comment: I am new here so couldn't edit the code properly, hence removed it !

Comment: The constructor of your `Caller` class gives `this` to a new thread and then starts the thread.  That's a mistake.  Even though the constructor assigns `target`, `msg`, and `t` before starting the new thread, the Java language does _not_ guarantee that the new thread will see those assignments.  You should learn more about the _Java Memory Model_ (Google it!), and specifcally, about the bugs that can be caused by _leaking this_.  (Google for Java "leaking this").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're starting three threads. Each of those will call `call` on the same `Callme`, so only one thread will be executing `call` at a time... but that doesn't mean that the threads will execute in the order that you started them.

Imagine you start a running race, and half way round the track you have a gate that only one person can pass through at a time. You start 10 runners at roughly the same time - why would you expect the runners to enter the gate in exactly the same order that you started them?

Basically, synchronization provides *exclusivity* - it doesn't specify *ordering*.

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Comment: If I set priority to threads such that c1>c2>c3 ,I should get the desired result ?

Comment: @Golden_flash: No. That's only a guideline, effectively.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If the order of Threads in not determined till run time , why do I get the same order [Hello] [World] [Synchronized] everytime the program is run even on different systems ?

Comment: @Golden_flash: I don't know, but it's still an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it. There are lots of things like that - HashMap ordering, for example, might be predictable on a single version of a single implementation, but you still shouldn't use it...

Comment: @Golden_flash Try solving problems like producer consumer or cigarette smokers problem using multiple threads, then you will get more clarity about what synchronization is doing and how you are achieving the order of threads accessing shared object. That should give you more clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Synchronized keyword is used to acquire the lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns, so only one thread can use that method at a time. And it is not necessary that you will get the same result each time, it may produces different results based on CPU availability to a thread.

You should read more about multithreading

Here's [a link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm)!